# Ephemeral model instances for demo in Django 1.10

Tags: python, django, postgresql, django-models

I need to dynamically create a series of models and relationships in a Postgres database for the purpose of demoing some features.

The issue is these models can't interfere with or be returned by queries in the normal functioning of the Django app. However they must have the full behavior set of the model and the ability to be returned by queries during the demo.

Using factories (we use Factory Boy primarily) is imperfect because the models can't be queried without being saved to the database at which point they interact with regular operation queries.

A second database is imperfect as well because the demo occurs during normal app operation and thus the "valid" model instances still need to be available.

Flagging the models as `is_demo` also won't work as there's a half dozen different types of models that need to be instantiated for the demo to work as intended.

I could clear the specific models that are created with a cron job or similar but they'd effect the database between creation and the scheduled job.

Running everything in a staging environment is acceptable, but the ideal answer allows me to run the demos on the production build.

Is there an accepted approach or useful library that I've missed?

A sample model that's involved in the demo:

```
class Transaction(models.Model):
    amount = models.DecimalField(max_digits=8, decimal_places=2, db_index=True,
                                 editable=False)
    assigned_user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    date = models.DateField(db_index=True, editable=False)
    description = models.CharField(max_length=255, null=True, blank=True)
    is_declined = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    is_pending = models.BooleanField(db_index=True)
    fi_account = models.ForeignKey(
        FinancialAccount, on_delete=models.CASCADE)



   @property
    def organization(self):
        org = self.fi_account.organization
        return org
```

We'd need to be able to query this model and use its `.organization` property successfully.  Without having it effect other queries.

Answer (score 1):

You could create a clone of your production environment (database and django app), then update your production codebase to include the demo features/fixes. This way you'd have a copy of the "valid" production models in addition to the new models you're demoing.

It sounds like you should have a "staging" environment that closely matches your production environment for situations just like this.

### Edit

One option I just thought of would be to create a `Demo` model which keeps track of records created as part of a demo. This `Demo` model would be have a `ForeignKey` to your `User` model, so each User can create/destroy their own demo (or your view can create it).

This would let you delete any records created as part of a specified `Demo` object.

However, you'd have to make sure you add an `exclude` for all of your current queries/filters of the models you have now.

Honestly, I'm not sure if what you're asking for can be done without exhaustively modifying all of your Model filters to exclude whatever demo records you create.

Comment: Thanks Nathan,

We do have a staging environment.  Ideally, we're able to run the "demo" in the prod environment.  That's a good fallback thought, I'll update.

Comment: I guess I'm not understanding what your production environment does that makes the staging environment unusable for your demo. Could you elaborate, especially on what you hinted at in your second paragraph? What does "the full behavior set of the model and the ability to be returned by queries" mean?

Comment: The production env is essentially identical to staging.  I'd like users/customers to be able to trigger and step through the demo with the "ephemeral data".  That would involve the demo working on production since users would obviously not be using the staging environment.  It might be easier to think of it as a tutorial, its not quite, but same idea.

Comment: It's kind of difficult to say much more without seeing some code, particularly your models.